# QuerySelector working in one page but not in another one and preventing dragover event?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, queryselector

I am using queryseletor to select this element:

```
<table class="table table-head-fixed text-nowrap">
   <ul class="ticketsContainer">
   </ul>
</table>
```

I did this:

```
const ticketsContainer = document.querySelector(".ticketsContainer");
```

And it is working fine in one page but in another it returns null don't know what I am doing wrong. And this prevent one of the `dragover` event below from working properly and
my console logs this error:

```
custom.js:132 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

sprintTicketContainers.forEach(sprintTicketContainer => {


  sprintTicketContainer.addEventListener("dragover", e => {
        e.preventDefault()
        const currentDraggingTicket = document.querySelector(".draggingTicket");
        const dragAfter = getDragAfterElement(sprintTicketContainer, e.clientY);
        if (dragAfter == null) {
            sprintTicketContainer.appendChild(currentDraggingTicket);
        } else {
            sprintTicketContainer.insertBefore(currentDraggingTicket, dragAfter);
        }

    });
});

ticketsContainer.addEventListener("dragover", e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const currentDraggingTicket = document.querySelector(".draggingTicket");
    const dragAfter = getDragAfterElement(ticketsContainer, e.clientY);
    if (dragAfter == null) {
        ticketsContainer.appendChild(currentDraggingTicket);
    } else {
        ticketsContainer.insertBefore(currentDraggingTicket, dragAfter);
    }

});
```

Which I was testing since they both do the same thing but in different pages.

Comment: Thanks for this editing Mr Brian.

Comment: Need a bit more information, but make sure the script that contains `const ticketsContainer = document.querySelector(".ticketsContainer")` is run before the script that contains `ticketsContainer.addEventListener("dragover",`

Comment: I guess yes since they are in the same file with the querySelector being on the first line and I thought I was about a DOM loading issue but apparently it is not.

Comment: In that case, as far as I can see, there is nothing wrong with the code. That error message eludes to document.querySelector(".ticketsContainer") not being able to find the element, so my only other thought would be to make sure the script is run after the DOM content has loaded. You can do this by placing the script at the bottom of the HTML, or adding the `defer` modifier to the script tag